# STOMP Over Websockets via Java

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, stomp

I have a WebSocket server which will receive STOMP over WebSocket messages from a client. The real client is using javascript to do [this](http://www.jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/).
But I want to create my test client in Java (I don't know javascript very well). The problem is the STOMP client libraries I have found for Java such as the one from ActiveMQ and stompj do not appear to support using WebSockets. I am completely new to the concept of STOMP and STOMP over WebSockets so I was wondering if I am missing something or if there really is no public support for doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12844654/289985. Just replace "PHP" with "Java", and you should have your answer.

Answer (score 3):

STOMP over WebSocket is supported, ActiveMQ supports STOMP http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html.

I think you have to include the javascript library provided in that link.